# What do the entity-relationship diagram (ERD) symbols used in DBeaver mean?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams, dbeaver

I don't understand the ERDs used by DBeaver. The diamonds and dots at the ends of the line arent the crow's foot I'm used to. I've googled the subject and [checked the docs](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/ER-Diagrams) but can't find a straight-forward answer.

Is there a reference for the style used? What do these symbols mean?

Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: I think [this page](https://data-xtractor.com/knowledgebase/er-notation/) explains it quite well with the same diagram in different notations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found something while putting together this question. It seems the current standard used is IDEF1x, according to [this github issue.](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1017)

I found [a PDF cheat sheet](http://www.32geeks.com/classes/resources/IDEF1X_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) with the following content showing all the relationships:

[image]

Comment: For the lazy, a wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X

Answer (score 3):

A link to the [IDEF1X notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X) is actually provided in DBeaver's online docs: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/ER-Diagrams/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an image from DBeaver Documentation showing relationship notations
This is the link:
https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Database-Structure-Diagrams/
[image: Here is an image from DBeaver Documentation showing relationship notations]